# What is the difference between Stack Overflow and Programmers SE?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, software-engineering-se

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Choosing between Stack Overflow and Programmers Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82988/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange)

I've been facing a dilemma. What kind of questions go to Stack Overflow? What kind go to Programmers SE?

Comment: Part of the confusion is caused by Programmers changing its focus during its time in Beta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As their FAQ state, *quoting each one of them* :

[**StackOverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) is for questions that cover :

> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - matters that are unique to the programming profession

While [**Programmers**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) :

> is for expert programmers who are
>   interested in subjective questions on
>   software development

And questions there

> can include topics such as:
>
> - Software engineering
> - Developer testing
> - Algorithm and data structure concepts
> - Design patterns
> - Architecture
> - Development methodologies
> - Quality assurance
> - Software law
> - Programming puzzles
> - Freelancing and business concerns

Comment: Good explanation. Never read the FAQ though. +1 if I could. But no previlage for that now. thank you :)